# How to use `React.createElement` children parameter (without jsx)

Tags: reactjs

`React.createElement` takes a spread "children" parameter

```
var d = React.DOM;

React.createElement(LabeledElement, {label: "Foo"}, 
     d.input({value: "foo"})
)
```

but I can't find any documentation on how to actually use it

```
var LabeledElement = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return d.label({}
            ,d.span({classNames: 'label'}, this.props.label)
            , //How to place children here? 
    }
})
```

I'm sure this has a really really simple answer.

Comment: James K Nelson from Frontend Armory wrote a n excellent article about how to use the `children` property: https://frontarm.com/james-k-nelson/4-ways-pass-children-react-elements/

Comment: React Enlightenment (Written by Cody Lindley – Sponsored by Frontend Masters) has an article about how to use the `children` property: https://www.reactenlightenment.com/react-nodes/4.2.html

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The children passed to a component, either via JSX nesting or via the third+ argument to `React.createElement`, shows up in the component as `this.props.children`:

```javascript
var MyLabel = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return React.createElement("label", {className: "label"},
      React.createElement("span", {className: "label"}, this.props.label),
      this.props.children
    );
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return React.createElement(MyLabel, {label: "Here is the label prop"},
      React.createElement("div", {},
        React.createElement("input", {type: "text", value: "And here is a child"})
      )
    );
  }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/typ1f2mf/; docs: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#children

Comment: Ah thanks. Never thought to look *inside* of `props`

Comment: how can we have 'style' as our prop for the child element. for example the child element is a paragraph tag and we want to specify a style like 'color: red' for it. can you help me please with it?

Comment: @MichelleTilley hi again. sorry but i used this piece of code and it threw an error saying " 'p' is not defined". p needs quotation just like your original answer but also after putting quotation, it doesn't work, saying "Style prop value must be an object". here is my code: 
`React.createElement('div', null, React.createElement('p', { style: "color: red" }), "Hello John")`
the error message in UI: Error: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.
please pay attention to my next reply.

Comment: @MichelleTilley but when i change the code above to this:
`React.createElement('div', null, React.createElement('p', { style: { color: 'red' } }), "Hello John")`
,it compiles successfully and the UI is what i expect to see except changing the color of that text to red. i mean the style doesn't actually work again. so i will really appreciate if you know how to use styles properly in this situation in React.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
var MyLabel = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return React.createElement("label", {className: "label"},
      React.createElement("span", {className: "label"}, this.props.label),
      this.props.children
    );
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return React.createElement(MyLabel, {label: "Here is the label prop"},
      React.createElement("div", {},
        React.createElement("input", {type: "text", value: "And here is a child"})
      )
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).